# Let's Evaluate a Little

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

How about we do a mini-evauluation like we did in March?  I've been wandering [/review](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/) and thought it be a good idea if we looked at average quality, so I'm cloning the March post.

On a side note, if you haven't used the new review tools, check out the new **[/review](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/)** now!

---

One of the most important aspects of being a Stack Exchange site is quality. Yes, there are lots of metrics that one can use to "measure" a site, but we don't really care about those as much as we care about a site providing expert answers to good questions. To that end, we're introducing a self-evaluation to our sites!

This process is currently still in the midst of being put together, but you all are going to be a lucky early-adopter! Here's a rough guide:

```
Below, you'll find ten questions randomly selected from your site.
For each question, search the internet for the question as if you were the asker!
If our answer is good (complete, well-written, answers the question, found in search results, etc) then vote it up!
If our answer is bad (incomplete, poorly-written, off-topic, unfindable, etc) then vote it down!
```

Comment with anything you feel is worth noting, or to explain your voting choice. We have a rough guide to better/par/worse right here. If your result is par, make a choice to vote up or down based on your instincts!

Ultimately, remember that our goal is to make the internet a better place. If you find yourself torn between the options, or if you can't decide, ask yourself: does this question and/or answer make the internet better? That should help you decide.

This eval will close on September 7th or something...

Answer (score 3):

### [What happens if I Move Out before my Lease Ends?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16244/what-happen-if-moving-out-before-lease-ends)

Consult the internet and compare this question and its answers to the results.  If it's better, vote up.  If it's worse vote down.  *Feel free to improve the question and answers*

Comment: Note: I went ahead and edited this question myself.  This is great content, but the question's grammar detracted from it significantly.

Comment: I hate it when People capitalize Words In A Sentence without any Reason For Doing So.  ;-)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I thought important words were still capitalized in "titles" :-).

Comment: The question highlights the confusion many people have about the purpose of a security deposit. It is for physical damages, not to serve as the last months rent.

Answer (score 0):

### [What's the point of a benchmark?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16222/whats-the-point-of-a-benchmark)

Consult the internet and compare this question and its answers to the results.  If it's better, vote up.  If it's worse vote down.  *Feel free to improve the question and answers*

Answer (score 0):

### [What is the dividend tax rate for UK stock](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16182/what-is-the-dividend-tax-rate-for-uk-stock)

Consult the internet and compare this question and its answers to the results.  If it's better, vote up.  If it's worse vote down.  *Feel free to improve the question and answers*

Answer (score 0):

### [1.4 million cash. What do I do?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16211/1-4-million-cash-what-do-i-do)

Consult the internet and compare this question and its answers to the results.  If it's better, vote up.  If it's worse vote down.  *Feel free to improve the question and answers*

Comment: it's = it is. The possessive is simply its. A minor pet peeve of mine. (I've been editing the 'answers' here.

Answer (score -2):

### [Fraudulent Options, and Losing Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16168/fraudulent-options-and-losing-money)

Consult the internet and compare this question and its answers to the results.  If it's better, vote up.  If it's worse vote down.  *Feel free to improve the question and answers*